# dynamically add elements attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating dynamic accordion elements with a table inside the accordion content. I need to set text dynamically via variables that are passed to the function.

My code:

```
function addAcc(marking, freq) {
    var newID = marking;

    var newTable = '<div id="startID"> \
                    <h3>\
                    </h3> \
                    <table class="tg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0;background-color:  #A0A6AB"> \
                    <tr> \
                    <th id="frequency"></th> \
                    <th></th> \
                    <th></th> \
                    <th></th> \
                    </tr> \
                    </table> \
                    </div>';

    $('.emitters').append(newTable)
    $('.emitters').accordion("refresh");
    $('#startID').attr('id',newID);
}
```

for Instance I need to set the  element frequency with a text value of the freq variable received when the function is called. one more issue is to set the main div ID dynamically with the marking string that is passed to the function.
How can those be set when the HTML code is a javascript variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please replace your function with below code to get expected output

```
function addAcc(marking, freq) {
var newID = marking;

var newTable = '<div id="'+marking+'"> \
                <h3>\
                </h3> \
                <table class="tg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0;background-color:  #A0A6AB"> \
                <caption>'+freq+'</caption>\
                <tr> \
                <th id="frequency"></th> \
                <th></th> \
                <th></th> \
                <th></th> \
                </tr> \
                </table> \
                </div>';

$('.emitters').append(newTable)
$('.emitters').accordion("refresh");
$('#startID').attr('id',newID);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the strings to set variables for your HTML code. For instance:

```
var newTable = '<div id="startID"> \
            <h3>\
            </h3> \
            <table class="tg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0;background-color:  #A0A6AB"> \
            <tr> \
            <th id=';

var frequency = freq;

var newTable2 = '></th> \
            <th></th> \
            <th></th> \
            <th></th> \
            </tr> \
            </table> \
            </div>';
```

And then:

```
$('.emitters').append(newTable + frequency + newTable2)
```